# Why Django 2.2.1 does not call get_absolute_url()

Tags: python, django

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) states that if `get_absolute_url()` method is defined on model then is used in Django Admin for "VIEW ON SITE" button:

> One place Django uses get_absolute_url() is in the admin app. If an
>   object defines this method, the object-editing page will have a “View
>   on site” link that will jump you directly to the object’s public view,
>   as given by get_absolute_url().

After some time of debugging I wonder why it is not called. And then I found that it is not even called in the source of Django.

https://github.com/django/django/blob/8b3f1c35dd848678225e8634d6880efeeab5e796/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L290

```py
        elif self.view_on_site and hasattr(obj, 'get_absolute_url'):
            # use the ContentType lookup if view_on_site is True
            return reverse('admin:view_on_site', kwargs={
                'content_type_id': get_content_type_for_model(obj).pk,
                'object_id': obj.pk
            })
```

Is it bug?

Comment: It's not a bug. If you look at what the `admin:view_on_site` view does, it calls `get_absolute_url()` and performs a redirect to this URL. https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/contenttypes/views.py#L35 . Voting to close because this doesn't seem to describe a specific problem that can be reproduced.

Comment: It does call it. You would need to show us your code where you expect it to be called for us to help.

Comment: @solarissmoke I though stackoverflow is where I can ask reasonable questions. Why do you think it should be a "specific problem that can be reproduced"? Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: I took a look at the link provided by @solarissmoke . There is indeed a call of `get_absolute_url()` from `shortcut()`, but it is still unclear how `reverse()` calls it. Basically I put `raise Exception('my exception')` in my model `get_absolute_url()` method and no exception. It is just not being executed. I also replaced `get_absolute_url()` method with an attribute of the same name `get_absolute_url = 'blahblah'`. This result to showing "VIEW ON SITE" button, no exception for string not being callable.

Comment: Link to the code I am debugging: https://github.com/groveco/django-sql-explorer/blob/master/explorer/models.py#L95

Comment: I think you've misunderstood how this all works. `reverse()` just generates a URL to the redirect view, that in turn calls `get_absolute_url()` and redirects to that view. Django uses an intermediate view to redirect to the object. It's still not clear what the actual problem you are facing is - the code in Django works perfectly fine. You're just looking for a call to `get_absolute_url()` in the wrong place.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thank you for the explanation. There was a change of domain name for the site, but it kept redirecting me to the older domain. It turned out that 1) I forgot to change domain name in Django sites framework, but did not even check it because was absolutely sure that I did change 2) After actual change I needed to restart Django because it seems that it was cached somewhere. Now problem is solved. Thank you very much.